# Duplicated suggestions/autocomplete in xml Android Studio

Tags: xml, android-studio, autocomplete

the truth is that I did not use Android Studio for a while, I came back, and I find that when I want to insert xml code, the autocompletion is duplicated in certain parts, for example, this does NOT happen when I want to add elements such as Buttons, EditTexts, as you can see below :

[image]

but I realized that in the attributes part, certain attributes are duplicated, and I say "certain" because, for example, the attribute of

```
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
```

It is not duplicated, but for example, these that you will see in the image below,

[image]

this is normal? Or is there an option that I am not aware of that is causing this? thanks since now.